# Wont insert data to Access Database, keep stuck on Open Connection

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-access, insert, ms-access-2013

I create a Learning Aplication for English kindergarten, and I got stuck on the editing form for insert data about sing a song...

Here's my program view:

[Editing Learning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaD9W.png)

```
Translate
Tambah = Add
Ubah = Edit
Simpan = Save
Batal = Cancel
Hapus = Delete
Cari = Find
```

Now the problem is, when i click SIMPAN (SAVE), nothing happened, i try click SAVE again, show up an error like this

[The Connection wasn't closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q97RN.png)

Here's the coding:

```
Public Class frmeditlearning
Dim baru, valid As String
Dim id1, judul1, video1, databaru As String
Dim cmd1 As New OleDbCommand(databaru, mycon)


Private Sub btntambahsing_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btntambahsing.Click
    'This is button for ADD when get clicked 
    txtjudul.Enabled = True
    txtvideo.Enabled = True
    txtid.Clear()
    txtid.Select()
    btnsingcarivideo.Enabled = True
    btnsimpansing.Enabled = True
    btnbatalsing.Enabled = True
    btnubahsing.Enabled = False
    btnhapussing.Enabled = False
    baru = True
    btntambahsing.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub btnsimpansing_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsimpansing.Click
    If txtid.Text = "" Or txtjudul.Text = "" Or txtvideo.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Empty textbox is not allowed!", "EMPTY TEXTBOX", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Return
    End If

    If baru = True Then
        mycon.Open()
        Dim noid, str As String
        str = "Select id from sing where (id = '" & txtid.Text & "')"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, mycon)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read
            noid = dr("id").ToString
            If txtid.Text = noid Then
                mycon.Close()
                MessageBox.Show("SAME ID CANNOT USED!", "DUPLICATE ID", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                Return
            Else
                If Not (txtid.Text = noid) Then
                    mycon.Open()
                    id1 = txtid.Text
                    judul1 = txtjudul.Text
                    video1 = txtvideo.Text
                    databaru = "INSERT INTO sing (id,judul,video) values(@id,@judul,@video)"

                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id1)
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@judul", judul1)
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@video", video1)
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()

                    mycon.Close()
                    btnbatalsing.PerformClick()
                End If
            End If
        End While
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance, sorry if my English is bad.

Comment: 1) DIM a, b, c as string defines only c as string. a and b will be variants. 2) You could at least tell in which line you get the error. Go step by step through the code.

Comment: I dont know multiple dim in one row code can affecting, thanks for telling me.. the error start from here >>>  If baru = True Then
        mycon.Open()  <<< Connection keep opening even the Save is fail.